# What kind of icon should I use for requests?

Tags: website-design, icon

I work on a platform where users post requests and other users are connected with them, so they come and solve the first users' problems. Pretty much like a freelancing website.
I need an appropriate icon for making a request - like.. a clock would be for fastness.
My question is what characteristics would fit the case.

Any advice, please?

Comment: Hi there. We like icon recommendation questions, but this one seems a bit too broad. We need more detail to be able to help, in particular, it'd be very useful if you could explain your thought process. What ideas have you had and why didn't they work?

Answer (score 2):

First thing that came to mind for a request icon is someone raising there hand.
Kind of like this: Anyways just a thought, might help you spark some ideas though.

Best of luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about

**A Magnifying Glass** 
[image]

Seek out something

**An exclamation** 
[image]

Conveys urgency

Comment: That is correct and I completely agree. But look the question. There are no details so i just shot them off the top of my head